# Как правильно перевести техзадание с английского? Slick Slider

Tags: slider-slick.js, перевод

Не могу до конца понять, что значит эта строка:

***Use Slick slider for hero section + relative slick slider for posts.***

Буквально я понял:

"Используйте Slick Slider для hero (главный, действующий) секции + relative (родственный, взаимный, релятивный) слайдер для сообщений ниже.

Это что 2 слайдера должны быть или по очереди нижние сообщения должны подниматься в слайдер? Дайте ссылку на похожий слайдер по возможности.

Фото части макета прилагаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Дайте ссылку на похожий слайдер» — Slick Slider это название [вполне конкретного слайдера](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: @andreymal, и там даже есть пример Slider Syncing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не могу до конца понять, что значит эта строка "Use Slick slider for hero section + relative slick slider for posts".

Используйте [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) для "hero" секции, плюс, взаимоотносящиеся к hero-слайдеру, дополнительные SlickSlider'ы для постов.

В [документации](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) приведен пример синхронизации нескольких слайдеров.

Под [Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) подразумевается самый большой и широкий (960 x 270) блок сверху.

Comment: Я так вижу, что под фотками в каждом слайдере должны находится ссылки. Получается, что посты из ссылками и фотками будут время от времени подыматься вверх. Спасибо за подсказку, а бы долго искал Slider Syncing